# Solaris 11.1 in boot loop

Tags: solaris, solaris-11, live-cd

Oracle support had me delete the Intel IXGBE driver (/kernel/drv/amd64/ixgbe) and replace it with a Debug Driver to test something.  I did this and then rebooted and am now stuck in a boot loop.  Right before it crashes, I see the image below on the screen.  Support has been slow to get back to me and I need this server back ASAP.

Do I just boot into "Single User Mode" off the DVD and then copy the correct IXGBE driver?  I can't find documentation on how to mount my root pool while on a Live DVD and replace files.  Why is a NIC driver preventing the system from booting anyway?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up booting into a different Boot Environment through GRUB and copying the file from the old boot environment into my current corrupted one:

```
beadm mount 'bootenviroment name' /a

mv /a/kernel/drv/amd64/ixgbe ixgbeBAD

cp /kernel/drv/amd64/ixgbe /a/kernel/drv/amd64/ixgbe 

beadm umount 'bootenviroment name'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try booting with -B disable-ixgbe=true. Here's more on adding kernel arguments in GRUB: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28983/glyas.html